# Options to speed up this R code run on cluster?

Tags: r, data.table, cluster-computing

I'm attempting to clean a data set using batch R on a cluster but cannot get my code to run quickly. The following "loop" appears to be the bottleneck.

```
data[, `:=`(begdate_new = ave(begdate, id, seq, FUN = min),
              enddate_new = ave(enddate, id, seq, FUN = max))]
```

I've cut the data set to 500 observations and found that the code only takes 200 miliseconds to run, yet the last R job that I submitted (with the full data set) has been running for nearly 3 days despite having requested 200GB of memory. For reference, my data set is 162MB and contains just over 6,000,000 observations and 9 variables.

I'd welcome any suggestions to speed things up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the `data.table`-canonical use of `by=`.

```r
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(id=sample(1:10, size=10000, replace=TRUE), seq=sample(1:3, size=10000, replace=TRUE), date=as.Date("2023-04-21") + sample(10000))
head(DT)
#       id   seq       date
#    <int> <int>     <Date>
# 1:     1     2 2036-11-09
# 2:     5     1 2047-12-11
# 3:     1     1 2036-05-18
# 4:     9     2 2049-12-21
# 5:    10     2 2031-01-27
# 6:     4     1 2045-02-18
bench::mark(
  orig = DT[, `:=`(begdate_new = ave(date, id, seq, FUN = min), enddate_new = ave(date, id, seq, FUN = max))],
  dtcanon = DT[, `:=`(begdate_new=min(date), enddate_new=max(date)), by=.(id, seq)]
)
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result            memory     time       gc      
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>            <list>     <list>     <list>  
# 1 orig         2.98ms   4.68ms      214.    7.09MB    48.7     22     5      103ms <dt [10,000 × 5]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 dtcanon     805.6µs  861.2µs     1131.   77.84KB     4.11   551     2      487ms <dt [10,000 × 5]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

(I'm using a single `date` instead of begin/end, but the effect is the same if you have two different date fields.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is the following. Tested with a base R data set, since you have posted none in the question.

```r
library(data.table)

# work on a subset of mtcars
relevant_cols <- c("gear", "carb", "disp", "drat")
df1 <- as.data.table(mtcars[relevant_cols])

df1[, c("begdate_new", "enddate_new") := list(min(disp), max(drat)), by = .(gear, carb)][]
#>     gear carb  disp drat begdate_new enddate_new
#>  1:    4    4 160.0 3.90       160.0        3.92
#>  2:    4    4 160.0 3.90       160.0        3.92
#>  3:    4    1 108.0 3.85        71.1        4.22
#>  4:    3    1 258.0 3.08       120.1        3.70
#>  5:    3    2 360.0 3.15       304.0        3.15
#>  6:    3    1 225.0 2.76       120.1        3.70
#>  7:    3    4 360.0 3.21       350.0        3.73
#>  8:    4    2 146.7 3.69        75.7        4.93
#>  9:    4    2 140.8 3.92        75.7        4.93
#> 10:    4    4 167.6 3.92       160.0        3.92
#> 11:    4    4 167.6 3.92       160.0        3.92
#> 12:    3    3 275.8 3.07       275.8        3.07
#> 13:    3    3 275.8 3.07       275.8        3.07
#> 14:    3    3 275.8 3.07       275.8        3.07
#> 15:    3    4 472.0 2.93       350.0        3.73
#> 16:    3    4 460.0 3.00       350.0        3.73
#> 17:    3    4 440.0 3.23       350.0        3.73
#> 18:    4    1  78.7 4.08        71.1        4.22
#> 19:    4    2  75.7 4.93        75.7        4.93
#> 20:    4    1  71.1 4.22        71.1        4.22
#> 21:    3    1 120.1 3.70       120.1        3.70
#> 22:    3    2 318.0 2.76       304.0        3.15
#> 23:    3    2 304.0 3.15       304.0        3.15
#> 24:    3    4 350.0 3.73       350.0        3.73
#> 25:    3    2 400.0 3.08       304.0        3.15
#> 26:    4    1  79.0 4.08        71.1        4.22
#> 27:    5    2 120.3 4.43        95.1        4.43
#> 28:    5    2  95.1 3.77        95.1        4.43
#> 29:    5    4 351.0 4.22       351.0        4.22
#> 30:    5    6 145.0 3.62       145.0        3.62
#> 31:    5    8 301.0 3.54       301.0        3.54
#> 32:    4    2 121.0 4.11        75.7        4.93
#>     gear carb  disp drat begdate_new enddate_new
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>